# Is there a way to see an iMessage someone unsent on your macbook?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro

Recently I heard that there was a way to view someone's unsent message on a macbook with imessages. While I'm pretty sure you can not see on your phone, there is apparently a way to open messages on the macbook and then view the unsent messages someone sent through there. Is that possible, and if it is what is the method that allows me to do so?

Comment: I only asked because I have friends who like to unsend funny messages immediately and make me try to guess them. They claim they can see my unsent messages but won't tell me, I am just curious. The never unsend on purpose because of an accident it is always intentional.

Comment: No worries I was joking too ;)

Comment: Funny. Have an answer for me tho? :)

Comment: Sorry I don't for now but I suggest you read the answers which are already posted :)

Answer (score 1):

You can’t see an undone/unsent message as that would defeat the purpose.  Messages sent using iMessage on a Mac running Ventura or an iPhone running iOS 16 can be edited for up to 5 times within 15 mins or unsent within two minutes.

If they have earlier versions of either, they might be able to see edited\unsent messages. However this is unlikely. From you comments:

> I only asked because I have friends who like to unsend funny messages…They claim they can see my unsent messages

Nobody can unsend messages unless using Ventura or iOS 16, which appears to be the case here.  Since everyone is apparently running current versions, then they can only see unsent messages after the two minute period has elapsed in which they become “sent.”

From Apple Support: [Unsend or edit a message on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/messages/unsend-or-edit-a-message-ichtd68328c6/mac)

> To unsend or edit messages, you must be using iMessage with macOS Ventura or later, iOS 16 or later, or iPadOS 16.1 or later. If your recipients have devices with earlier versions, they receive follow-up messages with the preface “Edited to” and your new message in quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the unsent messages on any device with iOS 15.6 or earlier, iPadOS 15.6 or earlier, or macOS 12 or earlier. However, devices running current software will delete the message so it cannot be retrieved.

https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/unsend-and-edit-messages-iphe67195653/ios